# SQL Server Alias for SharePoint Servers in a FARM

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sql-alias, failover

We are trying to create a SQL Alias as given on this link [SQL ALias](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/priyo/2013/09/13/sql-alias-for-sharepoint/)

We have 2 SQL Servers, one is the main server and other is the Mirror. The DBA alter these servers at any time.

What we need to specify at the server name? (Main server or mirror)
In future if the DBA Changes the mirror server to main, do we need to change in SQL Alias as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Alias you have to give the name of the Main SQL server for now, once the DB server failed over to mirrored server then you have to manually update the sql to point it to the mirror server. you have to compromise for 10 to 15 minute down time (depend how quickly you figured out the problem).

But there is another way to setup the mirroring properly In SharePoint 2010. check this article: [Configure availability by using SQL Server database mirroring (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207314(v=office.14).aspx#Configure3)